# Electron gun and oscilloscope

Tags: electronics

Aren't the electrons exhausted in the electron source of electron gun? And what is the fate of electrons that strike the sulphide coated screen to produce luminescence?

Comment: No, the power supply keeps supplying more electrons. The screen must conduct enough to drain the excess charges off (unless you like sparks).

Comment: The screen of oscilloscopes has to conduct electricity to remove the excess charge. Thankfully the current is in the (sub)mA range. If you look at old CRTs, the entire inside of the tube was coated to remove space charge which would have otherwise distorted the image and suppressed the brightness.

Comment: I think this question deserves a thorough answer including a circuit diagram. One should explain the *full* circuit starting from the power supply windings to the screen, and explaining exactly what "ground" means.